# How to structure models and use Doctrine in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I am switching over to Symfony for a project that I am working on but I need a little advice on how to structure the files when it comes to models and using doctrine.

I have a custom framework that I use, which in turns uses the MVC model. Pretty much all of my MYSQL database queries are stored in the models and I access them through the controller.

Now after looking at Symfony2, my interpretation is that "model" files in Symfony are called Servies. Is this correct?

I have also generated a number of Entities that correspond to my MYSQL database. My question here is do I place my custom Doctrine queries inside the Service files or do I create them inside the Entity files?

I'm a little unsure how to structure this.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Pretty much all of my MYSQL database queries are stored in the models

That's bad, but I'll mention about it later.

> Now after looking at Symfony2, my interpretation is that "model" files in Symfony are called Servies. Is this correct?

Queries should be done in either repositories or in some cases in services. 
If your query returns entities, then it should be repository for sure.

> My question here is do I place my custom Doctrine queries inside the Service files or do I create them inside the Entity files?

Entities should be plain PHP objects. They shouldn't depend on anything than other entities. Entities actually doesn't even know anything about database. It's pure object oriented business logic.

Again, all DB queries should be in repositories or services.

I would suggest to go through Symfony Book in first place, to get idea of how *"the Symfony way"* works.

Comment: I agree, and i would add that for a beginer, EVERY select queries should be in repository class

Comment: Thanks for the advice, spent years working with custom MVC frameworks in agencies. First time i've really switched to an open source one.

Answer (score 1):

Symfony is [**not**](http://fabien.potencier.org/what-is-symfony2.html) MVC framework:

> Symfony2 is really about providing the tools for the Controller part, the View part, but not the Model part [...] Symfony2 is an HTTP framework; it is a Request/Response framework.

And it is great. Symfony allows to make your model as you wish without any restrictions. The Doctrine (ORM and/or DBAL) is a separate set of libraries. You can use any other library, or build your own persistence layer abstraction, or work with native SQL through PDO/MySQLi/etc.

Service is just an object that registered in the container and have some dependencies. Services can doing anything. They can represent your model, but it is not a requirement.

- [Organizing Your Business Logic](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/business-logic.html) (The Symfony Best Practices)
- [Doctrine ORM Best Practices](https://ocramius.github.io/doctrine-best-practices/#/)